# Angular Js reuse directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am wondering if I can make an Angular Js directive then I can use it again on the run time

here is a simple example

```
app.directive('w34Directive',function(){
return{
    template : "<p>test</p>"
  }
})
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div w34-directive></div>
```

but if I have a button with ng-click function that do the following function in the controller

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.myContainer');
angular.element(elem).append("<div w34-directive></div>");
```

which mean that a new DOM uses the directive will be generated but actually the angular directives fire once on the page load so when I add the new DOM it just add an empty div tag without the template of the directive which is in this case :

```
<p>test</p>
```

any idea about how to overcome this ?

Comment: What you're looking for is how to `$compile` your directive once it is on the page. My question is why are you attempting to add the directive *after* the page has already been compiled?

Comment: dom code doesn't belong in controllers. Often a sign that should be working with data model not dom...and let angular manage the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using :

**[$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)**

Exemple :

```
 var el = $compile( "<div w34-directive></div>" )( $scope );
 angular.element(elem).append( el );
```